# Choosing between classes and structs

Tags: class, polymorphism, d, struct

A msdn article on C# named [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx) gives the following advice:

> Consider defining a structure instead of a class if instances of the
>   type are small and commonly short-lived or are commonly embedded in
>   other objects.
>
> Do not define a structure unless the type has all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> ```
> It logically represents a single value, similar to primitive types
> ```
>
> (integer, double, and so on).
>
> ```
> It has an instance size smaller than 16 bytes.
>
> It is immutable.
>
> It will not have to be boxed frequently.
> ```
>
> If one or more of these conditions are not met, create a reference
>   type instead of a structure. Failure to adhere to this guideline can
>   negatively impact performance.

I wonder what the answer would be in the case of D. So far I've simply used structs in all cases where I didn't need polymorphism. I don't know if size is also a consideration. Or anything else.

Comment: Are you talking about the programming language D? If so, you're talking about a completely different language to C# - it's a really bad idea to start trying to apply recommendations from one language and platform to a different one.

Comment: @John Skeet - isn't that why he's asking the question.  He's read about something that applies to C# and is asking what the case would be for D.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. Yes, I'm talking about D. Sorry for the confusion. I realize that the languages are different, it just made me wonder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that that advice definitely does *not* apply to D.

Structs are value types. Classes are reference types. Structs are normally on the stack (though they can be on the heap and pointed to with pointers). Classes are on the heap. Structs have no inheritance or polymorphism. Classes have inheritance and polymorphism.

It is *very* common to use structs in D. I think that the general rule is that if something doesn't need to have polymorphism, it should be a struct. The *primary* reason to choose a class over a struct is because you want inheritance and polymorphism.

The second reason would be if it just makes more sense for the type to be a reference type (e.g. a container should probably be a class, since copying it every time that you pass it to a function wouldn't be good). Structs *can* have reference semantics, but it's just cleaner to use classes for that.

And lastly, if a type has a lot of data in it and you don't need to have a copy of it whenever you pass it to a function, then it would be more efficient to make it a class and only copy it when you actually need to (though you *can* choose to just always pass it by ref instead).

D's structs are definitely fancier than C#'s structs, since they have destructors and [postblit constructors](http://www.d-programming-language.org/struct.html#StructPostblit). There are also no autoboxing issues in D, since D uses templates (similar to C++, albeit much more powerful and much easier to use) rather than generics. And if you need a pointer to a struct, it's easy to do. So, I really don't think that the advice for C# applies to D.

It seems to me that the C# advice stems from two issues:

1. The fact that structs are value types and thus have value semantics.
2. The fact that structs in C# have to deal with autoboxing and must be very worried about the cost of copying.

Structs are also value types in D, but they're powerful enough to be able to have reference semantics if you want to, and the addition of postblit constructors and destructors makes them useful for *far* more than what you can do with structs in C#. And since D doesn't have autoboxing, the concerns about autoboxing don't apply to D. You still don't want your structs to be huge, since unless you pass by ref, they're going to be copied whenever you pass them to a function, but it's definitely not as large a concern as it is in C#. It's much more in line with C++ in that regard.

And the advice about immutability does not apply *at all* to D. D structs are frequently mutable, and it would be a big problem if they weren't. Ranges, for instance, are usually implemented as structs, and that wouldn't be possible if you couldn't mutate them.

So, no, I don't think that the C# advice really applies to D. The situation between the two languages is just too different. It would be better to think of D's structs as C++ classes which don't have any base classes and can't be derived from, since that's far closer to what they actually are than C#'s structs.

Comment: Post-blit constructors aren't required for structures to have reference semantics.  A .net struct which wraps a private field of a mutable reference type which is only set in its constructor will generally exhibit reference semantics, *whether one wants it to or not*, since a copy of the struct will refer to the same object as the original.  I would expect the purpose of postblit constructors is to allow a struct that holds the only reference to a heap object to be able to change that object directly, rather than construct a new object which is different in the desired way.

Answer (score 8):

In D, there are a few key differences from C# that make it idiomatic to use `struct` more frequently:

1. There's no autoboxing because the problems it solves are typically solved with templates.
2. Right now, the garbage collector is less efficient.
3. Pointers to structs work well in most cases if you want reference semantics.  (The only major exception being that pointers to structs with overloaded arithmetic or indexing operators behave weirdly because the operations are treated as pointer arithmetic instead of calling operator overloads.)  Furthermore, structs can easily be heap allocated using the `new` operator.
4. Structs can have deterministic destructors (not finalizers), copy constructors, etc., so you can do similar kinds of magic with them as in C++.

I'd say a struct should be used anytime you don't need polymorphism and won't need it in the future and don't need reference semantics, or if you need deterministic destruction, copy construction, etc.  If you need polymorphism then you definitely need to use a class.

If you don't need polymorphism but want reference semantics then either a pointer to a heap-allocated struct or a final class would work well.   A final class is slightly nicer syntactically and doesn't run into weird corner cases when overloading arithmetic operators.  A struct avoids a few bytes of overhead by not having a vtable or a monitor.  If neither of these are important to you then it's just a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

structs are passed by value so size is indeed a consideration (though one can avoid that with `ref` and `in`)

mostly you should use structs when you need to pass by value only (changes to the object shouldn't propagate) or it's a short lived object whose lifespan is short enough to remain on  the stack (like a range object as you'll see in the `std.algorithm` module; all the functions there nearly all return a struct)

personally I've defined structs for data objects (the single value clause) like a 2d point and an angle with some convenience functions and operator overloading defined for them

Answer (score 0):

The same recommendations generally apply to D as in C# -- they're pretty much the same concepts.

The only exception is the *boxing* recommendation -- it doesn't apply, since boxing doesn't really exist natively in D.